# No Boot Device Found after installing Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, raid, megaraid

I have a Dell Precision T7910 Workstation with a MegaRAID SAS 9361-8i,
with one Virtual Drive of RAID 0 (one HDD of 512 Gb) and another Virtual Drive of RAID 45 (3 HDDs of 4To).

With the Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS, DVD installation, I install Ubuntu on the 512 Gb drive and it all goes well. However, after rebooting the system says "No Boot Device Found. Press any key to reboot the machine.".

I've read somewhere that UEFI must be enabled. Is this true? UEFI is currently disabled. However, if I try to enable it from the BIOS set-up, General -> Boot Sequence -> Boot list Option: Select "UEFI", then when I click "Add Boot Option", the BIOS says "File System Not Found!".

Comment: Change switch the RAID and AHCI modes in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the alternative Ubuntu installer, rather than the new subiquity installer.
https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads -> Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS alternative installer -> 64-bit PC (AMD64) server install image

More info:
[Installing "Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS" with Subiquity not working: "No Boot Device Found"](https://superuser.com/questions/1467066/installing-ubuntu-server-18-04-2-lts-with-subiquity-not-working-no-boot-devi)

Comment: ouch .. I only have the subiquity installer and have no means to create another installable usd/dvd ;( –

Comment: btw you _can_ accept your own answer