# Installing "Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS" with Subiquity not working: "No Boot Device Found"

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I install "Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS" with Subiquity (recommended approach on https://ubuntu.com/download/server ), and after the rebooting the system says "No Boot Device Found. Press any key to reboot the machine."

I tried installing from DVD, from USB flash, with different options (UEFI & secure boot enabled and disabled). The computer is a "Dell Precision T7910 Workstation" with a "MegaRAID SAS 9361-8i". I tried installing it on a Virtual Disk (RAID), or an HD without the RAID controller. Nothing worked.

Then I tried with the "alternative installer", and it worked fine: https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads -> Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS alternative installer -> 64-bit PC (AMD64) server install image

Any idea of what is the problem with the Subiquity installer?

Comment: ouch .. I only have the `subiquity` installer and have no means to create another installable usd/dvd ;(